# Using GDB to find were assertion failed (Discoverying STM32 Microcontroller book)

Tags: c, gdb, stm32f4discovery

I've been working my way through the Discoverying the STM32 Microcontroller book by Geoffrey Brown [Discoverying the STM32](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~geobrown/book.pdf) and one of the exercises (on page 60) is to modify the blinking led program to cause a assertion violation and use gdb to find the place in the code where this occurs. I can't really figure out how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated been at this for evening or two.

> Modify your program to cause an assertion violation – for example re- placing GPIOC with 66 when initializing the pin – and use GDB to ﬁnd the place in the library source code where an assertion failed.

```
#include <stm32f10x.h>
#include <stm32f10x_rcc.h>
#include <stm32f10x_gpio.h>

int main(void)
{
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

//Enable Peripheral Clocks (1)
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
//Configure Pins (2)
GPIO_StructInit(&GPIO_InitStructure);
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
//GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);
//Exercise for blinking light program
GPIO_Init(66, &GPIO_InitStructure);

//Configure SysTick Timer (3)
if(SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000))
    while(1);
while(1){
    static int ledval = 0;

    //Toggle led (4)
    GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_8, (ledval) ? Bit_SET : Bit_RESET);
    ledval = 1 - ledval;
    Delay(250); //Wait 250ms
 }
}

//Timer code (5)
static __IO uint32_t TimingDelay;

void Delay(uint32_t nTime){
   TimingDelay = nTime;
    while(TimingDelay != 0);
}

void SysTick_Handler(void){
    if(TimingDelay != 0x00)
        TimingDelay--;
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line){
    /* Infinite loop*/
    /* Use GDB to find out why we're here*/
    while(1);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Also I amen't sure if he means in GPIO_Init function where should change GPIOC to 66.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
(gdb) break __assert
```

EDIT

In the [stm32f10x_conf.h](https://github.com/spark/core-common-lib/blob/master/SPARK_Firmware_Driver/inc/stm32f10x_conf.h) file there is a function called `assert_failed`.

So try using `break assert_failed` instead and see if that works.

Comment: Won't this break on every assert?

Comment: Using this I get __assert is not a function. Dunno if doing anything wrong kinda new to gdb.

Comment: Just edited, see if this helps. Honestly I'm not familiar with STM32 but theoretically it should work assuming assertions are enabled. Also, you may have to uncomment the line `/* #define USE_FULL_ASSERT    1 */` and rebuild for assertion failures to work properly.

Comment: @dbrank0 It should break on every assertion failure, not every assert.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSampson it worked with the edit and commenting that like, seems to be over looked in the book